# Smart hashing with minimized conflicting on high frequency items

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I was thinking of hashing N items to K buckets, with the hope that the conflicting on high frequency items are minimized (pushing the conflicting to the buckets with less items). Is there some existing algorithm that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Cuckoo Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).